# Multiplication in column gridview yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How could I multiply two properties from model like this

```
['value' => ('items.order_items_quantity' * 'items.order_items_initialPrice')],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
    ...
    'value' => function($data) {
        return ($data->order_items_quantity * $data->order_items_initialPrice);
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[
    'attribute' => 'column1',
    'value' => function ($data, $key, $index, $column) {
        return $data->column1 * $data->column2;
    },
]
```